# What is a LEFT JOIN in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've seen a query using a `LEFT JOIN` as opposed to an `INNER` or `LEFT OUTER`.

What is a `LEFT JOIN` exactly?

Comment: All JOIN types of PostgreSQL are explained [in the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-JOIN) including examples. So basically the `OUTER` keyword is optional for `LEFT`, `RIGHT` and `FULL` joins.

Comment: A more graphic explanation: [Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Where an `inner join` returns only entries that match in both tables, a `left join` takes all the entries from first table and any that match in the second table. A `right join` is the reverse of a `left join` (ie: all from the second table)

So if TableA is

```
A B
1 a
2 b
3 c
```

and TableB is

```
A B
1 d
2 e
```

Then `Select * from TableA inner join TableB on TableA.A = TableB.A` returns

```
1 a 1 d
2 b 2 e
```

And `Select * from TableA left join TableB on TableA.A = TableB.A` returns

```
1 a 1 d
2 b 2 e
3 c null null
```

Comment: I think the results aren't right. First query should give 1 a 1 d / 2b 2 e Second query should give: 1 a 1 d / 2b 2 e / 3 c NULL NULL.

Answer (score 9):

It is the same as LEFT OUTER (The OUTER is implied because an INNER JOIN requires bilateral matching so a `LEFT INNER JOIN` would make no sense). The same applies for `RIGHT JOIN` and `FULL JOIN` these are equivalent to `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` and `FULL OUTER JOIN` respectively